# Lining up values from 2 diffent tables for a graph

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sets of dated data:

`| 9/15/2015 | 1400 | a |   |   |   | 9/15/2015 | 1400 | a |
| 9/15/2015 | 1401 | b |   |   |   | 9/15/2015 | 1398 | c |
| 9/15/2015 | 1398 | c |   |   |   | 9/16/2015 | 1401 | c |
| 9/15/2015 | 1397 | d |   |   |   | 9/17/2015 | 1402 | a |
| 9/16/2015 | 1398 | a |   |   |   | 9/17/2015 | 1403 | b |
| 9/20/2015 | 1399 | d |   |   |   | 9/20/2015 | 1404 | b |
| 9/21/2015 | 1401 | b |   |   |   | 9/20/2015 | 1406 | c |
|           |      |   |   |   |   | 9/20/2015 | 1407 | d |
|           |      |   |   |   |   | 9/20/2015 | 1408 | b |`

When graphed, I don't get all Dates  and items to display. it cuts off at the shortest table and the points don't line up if the dates are different on the same row.[image: Initial graph with this table]
To correct this I need to shift the data to match 
So r3c7 9/16/2015 is displayed. I need to add two rows in that table and fill them with the date that matches Column 1 Rows 3 and 4 and match the value in column 8 (1398) in order to get data to line up properly in the graph.

How can this be done via VBA since the differences in the table could be quite dramatic.
Or
Is there a better way to format the graphs to automatically line up all the data?

I am using code to generate the graph automatically. I have another question posted about that [Chart not Sizing to larger range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50827189/chart-not-sizing-to-larger-range)
The question I am asking here is an attempt to work around this.
  So here is what the desired out put should be to make the graphs line up and use the full range of both tables:

`| 9/15/2015 | 1400 | a |   |   |   | 9/15/2015 | 1400 | a |
|-----------|------|---|---|---|---|-----------|------|---|
| 9/15/2015 | 1401 | b |   |   |   | 9/15/2015 | 1400 |   |
| 9/15/2015 | 1401 |   |   |   |   | 9/15/2015 | 1398 | c |
| 9/15/2015 | 1398 | c |   |   |   | 9/15/2015 | 1398 |   |
| 9/15/2015 | 1397 | d |   |   |   | 9/15/2015 | 1398 |   |
| 9/16/2015 | 1398 | a |   |   |   | 9/16/2015 | 1398 |   |
| 9/16/2015 | 1398 |   |   |   |   | 9/16/2015 | 1401 | c |
| 9/16/2015 | 1399 | d |   |   |   | 9/16/2015 | 1401 |   |
| 9/17/2015 | 1399 |   |   |   |   | 9/17/2015 | 1402 | a |
| 9/17/2015 | 1399 |   |   |   |   | 9/17/2015 | 1403 | b |
| 9/20/2015 | 1401 | b |   |   |   | 9/20/2015 | 1404 | b |
| 9/20/2015 | 1401 |   |   |   |   | 9/20/2015 | 1406 | c |
| 9/20/2015 | 1401 |   |   |   |   | 9/20/2015 | 1407 | d |
| 9/20/2015 | 1401 |   |   |   |   | 9/20/2015 | 1408 | b |
|           |      |   |   |   |   |           |      |   |`

Note that dates are copied from 1 table to the other and the numeric value is copied downward.[image: Graph that depicts the values relative to the time period of either table]

Comment: What's your specific question though?  You've tagged as VBA - do you have any code to post?

Comment: Very confusing.  So the last image is your desired output, without the drawings?

Comment: In addition to your question being unclear, your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet which is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question.

Comment: @Tim Williams  I figured some VBA code would be required, however it may be able to be done via the graph format

Comment: @ashleedawg For the most part yes, but if a graph can automatically do it then I would be happy to use the graph to do the legwork

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the Markdown Table Generator, Didn't know that existed. As far as troubleshooting, I was asking more of a how too as opposed to how to correct a problem.

Comment: Can you post another example (could be a screen shot) to show exactly what you want for a result?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Will this help?

Comment: I won't be able to tell until I get back home in a few days. The datatable does not format properly on my phone. But it seems you may have found a good solution for your problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple and elegant solution that should work wonderfully.
I found the answer here:https://peltiertech.com/plot-two-time-series-with-different-dates/

Simply put all date values into one column!

`| 9/15/2015 | 1400 | a |      |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9/15/2015 | 1401 | b |      |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9/15/2015 | 1398 | c |      |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9/15/2015 | 1397 | d |      |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9/16/2015 | 1398 | a |      |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9/16/2015 | 1399 | d |      |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9/20/2015 | 1401 | b |      |   |   |   |   |   |
| 9/15/2015 |      |   | 1400 | a |   |   |   |   |
| 9/15/2015 |      |   | 1398 | c |   |   |   |   |
| 9/16/2015 |      |   | 1401 | c |   |   |   |   |
| 9/20/2015 |      |   | 1401 | a |   |   |   |   |
| 9/20/2015 |      |   | 1401 | b |   |   |   |   |
| 9/20/2015 |      |   | 1404 | b |   |   |   |   |
| 9/20/2015 |      |   | 1406 | c |   |   |   |   |
| 9/20/2015 |      |   | 1407 | d |   |   |   |   |
| 9/20/2015 |      |   | 1408 | b |   |   |   |   |`